# INSERT INTO using subquery

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery

**Q: Insert a customer Jake Smith who’s shipping address is “yknhl fr hluhw” and people can reach him at ‘1236548780’ & ‘jakesmith@email.com’ (use a sub query to get the address).**

The shipping address is in another table called **shipping_details**, which can be referenced using the **shipping_id_details** column.

I am unable to get it right.
[image: 1]

```
INSERT INTO assignment2.customers(first_name, last_name, email, phoneNo, shipping_details_id)
VALUES('Jake', 'Smith', 'jakesmith@email.com', '1236548780',
       SELECT FROM assignment2.shipping_details 
       WHERE address = 'yknhl fr hluhw'))
```

Table structures:

```
assignment2.customers 
(customer_id, first_name, last_name, email, phoneNo, shipping_detail_id) 

assignment2.shipping_details 
(shipping_detail_id, address, city, province)
```

Comment: What are the table structure for both `assignment2.customers` and `assignment2.shipping_details` tables?

Comment: table assignment2.customers has six columns (from left to right)

customer_id, first_name, last_name, email, phoneNo, shipping_detail_id

table assignment2.shipping_details has 4 columns (from left to right)

shipping_detail_id, address, city, province

Comment: I don't really understand the question part where it says **_"(use a sub query to get the address)"_** because its clearly easier to achieve this with a join and without having to explicitly define `VALUES`. Is this an exam question? or just a training question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query like following...

```
INSERT 
INTO assignment2.customers( 
  first_name
  , last_name
  , email
  , phoneNo
  , shipping_details_id
) 
VALUES ( 
  'Jake'
  , 'Smith'
  , 'jakesmith@email.com'
  , '1236548780'
  , ( 
    SELECT
      shipping_detail_id 
    FROM
      assignment2.shipping_details 
    WHERE
      address = 'yknhl fr hluhw'
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the part about a subquery, below is a sample query. For further help, see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

```
INSERT INTO assignment2.customers
(first_name
, last_name
, email
, phoneNo
, shipping_details_id
)
SELECT 'Jake'
     , 'Smith'
     , 'jakesmith@email.com'
     , '1236548780',
     ,  x.shipping_details_id
  FROM assignment2.shipping_details x
 WHERE x.address = 'yknhl fr hluhw'
-- LIMIT 1
```